# How to automatically call laravel cron jobs while website is running

Tags: laravel, task

I am working with task scheduling in laravel. It's working well by using artisan command in cmd. But what's the problem with automatically calling the task on server. It's not running every minute.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

You will need to setup a cron job on your server that calls your scheduler

Answer (score 0):

If you using Laravel Scheduler, you have to access in your server via ssh.

```
ssh user@<IP-address>
```

edit crontab file to call every minute `php artisan schedule:run` artisan command.

So:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

If it not start,try to restart the web server. If you are using nginx, for ex.: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`